# Fuzzy file search in Linux console

Tags: linux, bash, file-search

Does anybody know a way to perform a quick fuzzy search on the Linux console?

Quite often I come across situations where I need to find a file in a project but I don't remember the exact filename.

In the [Sublime text editor](https://www.sublimetext.com/2) I would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> and type a part of the name, which will produce a list of files to select from. That's an amazing feature I'm quite happy with. The problem is that in most cases I have to browse code in a console on remote machines via ssh. I'm wondering if there is a tool similar to the "Go Anywhere" feature for the Linux console?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You may find [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) useful. It's a general purpose fuzzy finder written in Go that can be used with any list of things: files, processes, command history, Git branches, etc.

Its install script will setup a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keybinding for your shell. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> lets you fuzzy-search for a file or directory and put its path on your console.

The following GIF shows example usage of fzf including its [Vim integration](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim):

[image: Animation of using FZF]

Comment: sounds good. Could you make a youtube video about it? I also want to know how you insert kill -9 <number> so quickly.

Comment: How do I jump directly to a file with `fzf`? If i write `fzf` in terminal I find the location of a file:  if I press enter it just shows me the path as if in `echo` command. I'd like to find and access a file, whatever the extension type, not only for vim but for images and pdf and so on.

Comment: @nilon: You might find [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403916/getting-started-with-fzf-on-arch-linux/403917#403917) of mine helpful to get started with fzf.

Answer (score 7):

Most of these answers won't do fuzzy searching like sublime text does it -- they may match part of the answer, but they don't do the nice 'just find all the letters in this order' behavior.

I think this is a bit closer to what you want. I put together a special version of cd ('fcd') that uses fuzzy searching to find the target directory. Super simple -- just add this to your bashrc:

```
function joinstr { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }
function fcd { cd $(joinstr \* $(echo "$*" | fold -w1))* }
```

This will add an * between each letter in the input, so if I want to go to, for instance,

```
/home/dave/results/sample/today
```

I can just type any of the following:

```
fcd /h/d/r/spl/t
fcd /h/d/r/s/t
fcd /h/d/r/sam/t
fcd /h/d/r/s/ty
```

Using the first as an example, this will execute `cd /*h*/*d*/*r*/*s*p*l*/*t*` and let the shell sort out what actually matches.

As long as the first character is correct, and one letter from each directory in the path is written, it will find what you're looking for. Perhaps you can adapt this for your needs? The important bit is:

```
$(joinstr \* $(echo "$*" | fold -w1))*
```

which creates the fuzzy search string.

Comment: FYI, fzf (from the other comment) does exactly that, for command history, file listing, and whatever extra thing you wanna pipe into it. Bonus: live update, highlighting and gradual async indexing (doesn't block when you're fuzzy matching a directory of 30k files).

Comment: Agreed! Since writing that answer I stumbled across fzf somewhere along the way, and now that's what I use. Great tool.

Comment: `shopt -s nocaseglob` before the `find /home/user/*fuzzy*/*file*/*search*/` will make case insensitive to match: `/home/user/fuzzy/FILE/Search/` or whatever

Answer (score 5):

I usually use:

```
ls -R | grep  -i [whatever I can remember of the file name]
```

From a directory above where I expect the file to be - the higher up you go in the directory tree, the slower this is going to go.

When I find the the exact file name, I use it in find:

```
find . [discovered file name]
```

This could be collapsed into one line:

```
for f in $(ls --color=never -R | grep --color=never -i partialName); do find -name $f; done
```

(I found a problem with ls and grep being aliased to "--color=auto")

Comment: If the searched item may be hidden, you may alternate command like:
`ls -laR | grep  -i [fuzzy file name]` (added l (long format) and a (all files, including those dotted files) before R).

Answer (score 5):

The [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) shell script is probably worth taking a look at too.

> `fasd` offers quick access to files and directories for POSIX shells. It is inspired by tools like autojump, z and v. Fasd keeps track of files and directories you have accessed, so that you can quickly reference them in the command line.

It differs a little from a complete find of all files, as it only searches *recently opened* files. However it is still very useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -iname '*foo*'
```

Case insensitive find of filenames containing `foo`.

Comment: Correct usage as in...?

Comment: When I run this, it fails with `find: illegal option -- i`. I'm on a Mac right now though. Maybe `find` works differently between Mac and Linux.

Comment: Yes, OSX ships its own versions of most basic utilities. The example I wrote is for GNU find.

Comment: @evanrmurphy: the code sample simply was wrong, the first parameter `find` takes is the folder to search; I've taken the liberty to fix the code using the current folder (`.`) as an example; OSX / GNU find are no different in that respect

Comment: @scc: ah yes, somehow I missed that missing dot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how familiar you are with the terminal, but this could help you:

```
find | grep 'report'
find | grep 'report.*2008'
```

Sorry if you already know `grep` and were looking for something more advanced.

Comment: That's really not how you use find. Use `find . -name 'report*2008'`.

Comment: @Chris You need to quote your search pattern to prevent the shell from expanding the glob. +1 for the point made.

Comment: @Chris That's not what I was looking for but what's wrong with `find | grep 'report.*2008'` form?

Comment: @nab it's ridiculously inefficient.

Comment: @Chris This is obviously not supposed to be run from `/`. For an average project of 10K - 100K files this will work just fine.

Comment: @nab I'm sorry, there's really no argument here. My version is shorter to write and more efficient. If you really like slowing down things as a matter of habit, go for it. But when telling someone else, use the generally accepted (general case) way.

Comment: When I wrote my answer, I considered that my audience (i.e., the OP) is a beginner. I definitely didn't bother about performance here. I think that for beginners it's nice to know about a command that finds files, another one that filters and a way to compose them.

Comment: The "unix way" is the source of some of the worst shell scripts and practices out there. You don't need to start beginners off with bad habits.

Comment: I'm with Chris and jordanm on this... Beginner or not, do it right the first time. Piping the output of a command like find into another means you're spawning a grep process for each line find returns, which is utterly stupid and irresponsible to do as an admin. Find is heavy already on a CPU, you don't want to ad more when you can avoid it. See my answer which uses find2perl. It's much faster than find too!

Comment: underrated, it fills exactly what I need and it's efficient enought for an instant response

Answer (score 2):

> [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) is a simple, fast and user-friendly alternative to find.

Demo from the GitHub project page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try
[AGREP](http://www.tgries.de/agrep/) or something else that uses the [TRE](http://laurikari.net/tre/) Regular Expression library.

*(From their site:)*

```
TRE is a lightweight, robust, and efficient POSIX compliant regexp matching library with some exciting features such as approximate (fuzzy) matching.
At the core of TRE is a new algorithm for regular expression matching with submatch addressing. The algorithm uses linear worst-case time in the length of the text being searched, and quadratic worst-case time in the length of the used regular expression. In other words, the time complexity of the algorithm is O(M2N), where M is the length of the regular expression and N is the length of the text. The used space is also quadratic on the length of the regex, but does not depend on the searched string. This quadratic behaviour occurs only on pathological cases which are probably very rare in practice.

TRE is not just yet another regexp matcher. TRE has some features which are not there in most free POSIX compatible implementations. Most of these features are not present in non-free implementations either, for that matter.

Approximate pattern matching allows matches to be approximate, that is, allows the matches to be close to the searched pattern under some measure of closeness. TRE uses the edit-distance measure (also known as the Levenshtein distance) where characters can be inserted, deleted, or substituted in the searched text in order to get an exact match. Each insertion, deletion, or substitution adds the distance, or cost, of the match. TRE can report the matches which have a cost lower than some given threshold value. TRE can also be used to search for matches with the lowest cost.
```

Comment: That's very vague without explaining why he would want to use TRE regex. What does it offer that ERE or PCRE doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
grep -iR "text to search for" .
```

where "." being the starting point, so you could do something like

```
grep -iR "text to search" /home/
```

This will make grep search for the given text inside every file under /home/ and list files which contain that text.

Answer (score 1):

You can try c- ([Cminus](https://github.com/whitebob/cminus)), a fuzzy dir changing tool of bash script, which using bash completion. It is somehow limited by only matching visited paths, but really convenient and quite fast.

[image]

GitHub project: [whitebob/cminus](https://github.com/whitebob/cminus)

Introduction on YouTube: https://youtu.be/b8Bem53Cz9A

Answer (score 0):

You could use find like this for complex regex:

`find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -iregex ".*YOUR_PARTIAL_NAME.*" -print`

Or this for simplier glob-like matches:

`find . -type f -name "*YOUR_PARTIAL_NAME*" -print`

Or you could also use find2perl (which is quite faster and more optimized than find), like this:

`find2perl . -type f -name "*YOUR_PARTIAL_NAME*" -print | perl`

If you just want to see how Perl does it, remove the `| perl` part and you'll see the code it generates. It's a very good way to learn by the way.

Alternatively, write a quick bash wrapper like this, and call it whenever you want:

```
#! /bin/bash
FIND_BASE="$1"
GLOB_PATTERN="$2"
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Syntax: $(basename $0) <FIND_BASE> <GLOB_PATTERN>"
else
        find2perl "$FIND_BASE" -type f -name "*$GLOB_PATTERN*" -print | perl
fi
```

Name this something like `qsearch` and then call it like this: `qsearch . something`

Answer (score 0):

Search **zsh** for *file or folder* in terminal and *open or navigate* to it with combination of **find**, **fzf**, **vim** and **cd**.

Install [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) in [zsh](https://www.zsh.org) and add script to `~/.zshrc`, then reload shell `source ~/.zshrc`

```
fzf-file-search() {
   item="$(find '/' -type d \( -path '/proc/*' -o -path '/dev/*' \) -prune -false -o -iname '*' 2>/dev/null | FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%} --rev    erse --bind=ctrl-z:ignore $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS $FZF_CTRL_T_OPTS" $(__fzfcmd) -m "$@")"
  if [[ -d ${item} ]]; then
    cd "${item}" || return 1
  elif [[ -f ${item} ]]; then
    (vi "${item}" < /dev/tty) || return 1
  else
    return 1
  fi
   zle accept-line
}
zle     -N   fzf-file-search
bindkey '^f' fzf-file-search
```

Press keyboard shortcut `'Ctrl+F'` to run it, this can be changed in `bindkey '^f'`. It searchs (*find*) through all files/folders (*fzf*) and depending on file type, navigate to directory (*cd*) or open file with text editor (*vim*).

Also quickly open recent files/folders with [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd):

```
fasd-fzf-cd-vi() {
   item="$(fasd -Rl "$1" | fzf -1 -0 --no-sort +m)"
  if [[ -d ${item} ]]; then
    cd "${item}" || return 1
  elif [[ -f ${item} ]]; then
    (vi "${item}" < /dev/tty) || return 1
  else
    return 1
  fi
   zle accept-line
}
zle -N fasd-fzf-cd-vi
bindkey '^e' fasd-fzf-cd-vi
```

Keyboard shortcut `'Ctrl+E'`

Check other usefull tips and tricks for fast navigation inside terminal https://github.com/webdev4422/.dotfiles