# Easier navigation in *nix shell

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zsh

For some time, I am using [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump) for navigation in my filesystem. It does pretty good job, but I would like it to be capable of opening files (in my favorite editor) -- [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) does this. Unfortunately, fasd doesn't have any commits for more than two years. I've also looked at [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) but there is no zsh completion.

Is there an actively developed project similar to fasd, fzf ot autojump these days? (with fasd feature set)

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439121/fuzzy-file-search-in-linux-console) question.

Answer (score 0):

That will look like publicity, (*that kind of is*), but a zsh plugin I develop could help you to do that.

It's not exactly the same way of working than `fasd` or `autojump` since you have to register and name your *favorite* directory. (this of course can be stored in a config file, and I am considering adding learning taking inspiration on fasd.)

One registered, you get both a variable to refer to the directory, and a dispatcher alias to jump to the directory, subdirectory, execute some commands and so forth and so on.
Completion is supported for the subdirectory, and will add it soon for the `edit`subcommand.

If you want to give a look,  [here is the github repo and the readme](https://github.com/AdrieanKhisbe/diractions), if you want to give a try, and have `antigen` just run `antigen bundle AdrieanKhisbe/diractions`

Answer (score 0):

Answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69686155/13658418 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69685874/13658418

Add to `~/.zshrc`:

```
fasd-fzf-cd-vi() {
   item="$(fasd -Rl "$1" | fzf -1 -0 --no-sort +m)"
  if [[ -d ${item} ]]; then
    cd "${item}" || return 1
  elif [[ -f ${item} ]]; then
    (vi "${item}" < /dev/tty) || return 1
  else
    return 1
  fi
   zle accept-line
}
zle -N fasd-fzf-cd-vi
bindkey '^e' fasd-fzf-cd-vi
```

`Ctrl-E` to search/navigate with *fasd*, *fzf*, *vim* and *cd*: