# How you are using outside navigation in VIM with FASD and FZF?

Tags: vim, fzf, fasd

Did you find any comfortable workflow where you use file navigation with FASD or fzf and VIM. I have a problem with getting recent files open in VIM because FASD do not catch them. I'm looking for some tips.

Comment: _I have a problem with getting recent files open in VIM_ check this https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify. Probably your question is off-topic.

Comment: I don't have any problem with fasd or fzf or qs,dqsdg because I don't use them. Learn to use Vim's built-in commands instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FASD workflow:**

put the following line in your `~/.zshrc`

`alias v='f -t -e vim -b viminfo`

Then you can type in terminal

`v myP<TAB>`

to make it tab-complete the recent files of vim

`v myProject`

**FZF workflow:**

Put the following script in `~/.zshrc`:

```
ctrlp() {
  local selected
  if selected=$(find . -type f | grep -v .git | grep -v node_modules | fzf -q "$LBUFFER"); then
    LBUFFER=$selected
  fi  
  zle redisplay
}

# option-g to find files and put the result in command
zle -N ctrlp
bindkey "\eg" ctrlp
```

Use `<option>-g`(`<alt>-g` for windows) to open `fzf` and select a file. The selected file path will be put in the terminal. Then add `vim` before the path to open it in `vim`. More examples can be found at [fzf wiki](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples).

Since `fasd` doesn't support [neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim), I made a similar tool for it. Please check it out: https://github.com/haifengkao/nfasd

Comment: and what config for: `eval "$(fasd --init auto)"` are you using?

Comment: @regedarek I don't have this line in my .zshrc. I use oh-my-zsh plugins intead. `plugins=(git zsh-syntax-highlighting vi-mode zle-vi-visual opp surround fasd zsh-completions)`

Answer (score 1):

Extremely fast way to navigate **ZSH** in terminal is combination of **FASD**, **FZF**, **VIM** and **CD**.
Add script to `~/.zshrc`

```
fasd-fzf-cd-vi() {
   item="$(fasd -Rl "$1" | fzf -1 -0 --no-sort +m)"
  if [[ -d ${item} ]]; then
    cd "${item}" || return 1
  elif [[ -f ${item} ]]; then
    (vi "${item}" < /dev/tty) || return 1
  else
    return 1
  fi
   zle accept-line
}
zle -N fasd-fzf-cd-vi
bindkey '^e' fasd-fzf-cd-vi
```

Keyboard shortcut `'Ctrl+E'` to run it, can be changed in `bindkey '^e'`.
It searchs (*fzf*) through recent (*fasd*) files/folders and depending on file type, navigate to directory (*cd*) or open file with text editor (*vim*).

Also check other usefull tips and tricks for fast navigation inside terminal https://github.com/webdev4422/.dotfiles

Comment: I found it more user-friendly to run `zle reset-prompt` at the end, as suggested in [zsh: refresh prompt after running zle widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52325626/1333025).