# zsh: refresh prompt after running zle widget

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I have the following widget defined

```
function cdd()
{
    cd /
}
zle -N cdd{,}
bindkey "^R" cdd
```

After pressing the key combination the cwd is already changed, but the terminal prompt is not updated. Example, after doing this ()

```
~/tmp/todelete$ | # press key ^R  here; "~$" is the prompt; "|" denotes cursor
```

the terminal remains exactly unchanged. If I then type `ls -ld .`, it shows

```
~/tmp/todelete$ ls -ld .
dr-xr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Sep 14 07:52 ./

/$ |
```

which means the `cwd` at the time `ll` is running is already `/`.

This is very confusion and may lead to serious errors. (e.g. If after pressing `^R` I was interrupted to leave my desk and then come back, I might forget what I have done)

How can I let the terminal to redraw the prompt after pressing the key? Is there a `zle` function to do this?

Comment: There is a widget (`clear-screen`) to clear the screen and redraw the prompt, but I don't see a way to only redraw the prompt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`reset-prompt` could rescue:

```
function cdd()
{
    cd /
    zle reset-prompt # XXX: added
}
```

> `reset-prompt`
>
> Force the prompts on both the left and right of the screen to be re-expanded, then redisplay the edit buffer. This reflects changes both to the prompt variables themselves and changes in the expansion of the values (for example, changes in time or directory, or changes to the value of variables referred to by the prompt).
>
> Otherwise, the prompt is only expanded each time zle starts, and when the display as been interrupted by output from another part of the shell (such as a job notification) which causes the command line to be reprinted.
>
> --- [zshzle(1), reset-prompt, Miscellaneous, Widgets, zsh command line editor](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-reset_002dprompt)