# I need to search for a non-exact match on unix and i cannot do it with grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep, bigdata

I know on the file A, has a string that contains dc034 however, i cannot get that with grep command either using the word count or by searching for the string. 
What am i doing wrong? Suggestions

```
 grep "dc034" filedirectoryA | wc
    0       0       0

grep -Fv "dc034" filedirectoryA
```

Comment: Can't really guess. From what you've typed, it looks like the file doesn't have the string in question. Perhaps the string is not really there but it's some non-ascii character that looks similar to the characters you typed. What is the file?

Comment: related: 1. [for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439121/fuzzy-file-search-in-linux-console?s=1|2.1501) 2. [strings in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355972/fuzzy-string-matching-with-grep?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Show some example data

Comment: `grep -Fv` would grep lines not matching "dc034". Also is filedirectoryA a file or a directory.If its a directory, then try `grep "dc034" filedirectoryA/*`

Comment: If `grep "dc034" filedirectoryA` and `grep -v "dc034" filedirectoryA` both produce no output then your file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter asterisk(*) before and after the string and try to search.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search for *non-exact match* with `grep`.

Only thing you could do is search ***case-insensitively***:

```
grep -i "dc034" filedirectoryA
```

Or are you trying to do fuzzy search on Unix?  [agrep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep) exists in some distros. [githup agrep](https://github.com/Wikinaut/agrep) looks like a revived open source release. Might help too.

Failing that, see if you can find [`tre-agrep`](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/) for your distro.

Hope this helps;

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu still have agrep in their repositories, Gentoo as well