# How to bind fzf to zsh key?

Tags: linux, vim, zsh, fzf

I have fzf fuzzyfinder set up on Ubuntu 18.xx

fzf finds the file but it prints on the terminal when I select it.

How can I add a shortcut to zsh for fzf so that the selected file opens in vim instead of outputting the file name on terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Below script binds `<Ctrl+e>` to fzf search so that the selected file gets opened in vim

```
bindkey -s '^e' 'vim $(fzf)\n'
```

Add it to your .zshrc so it loads everytime you open zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69686155/13658418

Add script to `~/.zshrc`

```
fzf-vi-file() {
   file="$( find '/' -type d \( -path '/proc/*' -o -path '/dev/* \) -prune -false -o -type f -iname '*' 2>/dev/ | fzf -1 -0 --no-sort +m)" && (vi "${file}" < /dev/tty) || return 1
   zle accept-line
}
zle -N fzf-vi-file
bindkey '^e' fzf-vi-file
```

Bind to `Ctrl+E` = `bindkey '^e'`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30155602)